# Can I use a 130V AC adapter for my european laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-xps

I have an old Dell XPS Studio 16 whose AC adapter broke a while ago. I've been using a universal adapter, but apparently Dell has some hardware checks hard coded that won't let the adapter charge the battery unless it's a certified Dell adapter.

So I need a new one. It's pretty easy to find AC adapters on Amazon for $20 or so, but they're three-pronged versions for US outlets. We have 230V in our walls. It doesn't specifically say "130V AC to DC adapter" on them however. So I'm wondering if an adapter made for the US market will work if I find the right cable?

Comment: If they don't say it specifically its very unlikely the cable is rated for 230V.  Of course without specifics we can only guess which will not answer your question.

Comment: The adapter itself (the big power block) is almost certainly universal voltage. As for the power cord, see the linked question.

Comment: The AC adapter should specify the input voltage on it, in which case it will state whether 230V is OK.  I wouldn't trust any AC adapter that doesn't contain this information (I believe it's required, at least in the US).  If the AC adapter is designed to work with 230V, the cable sold with it should be fine with the correct outlet plug adapter.